# Is there a way to query table with the value of a particular data field

Tags: multi-index, rpc

Is there a way to query table with the value of a particular data field (for example, a token value) when using 'get_table rpc'? Only users whose token value is greater than 30 are output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_table_rows` with `index_position`, `key_type`, and `encode_type` options or use `get_table_by_scope` with other options like `lower_bound`, `upper_bound`, `limit`, and `reverse`

I will leave links to those [API](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_table_rows) and one to [cleos get table](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-get-table) which uses the same API and should help you get a grasp of their usage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But are there any examples that are clearly visible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can make a query with a value only when its index exists. For example, if you want to find token balance larger than some amount, its multi_index would be like this:

```
struct [[eosio::table]] accounts {
  name owner; // eosio.token doesn't have this field, because owner is scope
  asset balance;

  uint64_t primary_key() const { return owner.value; }
  uint64_t by_balance() const { return static_cast<uint64_t>(balance.amount); }
};

typedef eosio::multi_index<"accounts"_n, accounts,
   indexed_by<"balance"_n, const_mem_fun<accounts, uint64_t, &accounts::by_balance>>
> accounts_index;
```